# Plotcube with a fixed display area and customized double-click-handler

Tags: ilnumerics

I need a Plotcube with fixed display area and a double click handler that restores this view.
For that I derived a class from ILPlotcude and put the following code for setting the limits in its constructor:

```
:
float max = 1000f;
Limits.YMax = max;
Limits.XMax = max;
Limits.ZMax = max;
Limits.YMin = -max;
Limits.XMin = -max;
Limits.ZMin = -max;
AspectRatioMode = AspectRatioMode.MaintainRatios;
:
```

I have also installed a doubleClick-handler in this class with the code above and a additional line to reset the rotation:

```
:
if (args.Cancel) return;
if (!args.DirectionUp) return;
Rotation = Matrix4.Identity;
float max = 1000f;
Limits.YMax = max;
Limits.XMax = max;
Limits.ZMax = max;
Limits.YMin = -max;
Limits.XMin = -max;
Limits.ZMin = -max;
AspectRatioMode = AspectRatioMode.MaintainRatios;

args.Refresh = true;
args.Cancel = true;
:
```

The handler is executed but nothing happens. For testing purposes, I put the same code directly into the function OnMouseDoubleClick of of base class ILPlotCube (instead of the function call reset ()).
This works as expected, but it cannot be the final solution.

Has anyone an idea, what's wrong ?

Comment: You should post a small and runnable example!

Answer (score 0):

A mouse event handler is commonly registered on the *global* scene. Each panel / driver creates its own synchronized copy of that scene for rendering afterwards. The user interacts with the synchronized copy for rotation, pan etc. And it is the synchronized copy which fires the event handlers.

But since the custom event handler has been *registered* on the global scene, the handler functions will be *executed* on the node object within the global scene. Therefore, one should always use the `sender` object provided by the event handler in order to access scene node objects.

This example will register a mouse handler on the first plot cube object contained in the common (global) scene. The handler will reset the scene to some custom view:

```
ilPanel1.Scene.First<ILPlotCube>().MouseDoubleClick += (s,a) => {

    // we need the true target of the event. This may differs from 'this'!
    var plotcube = s as ILPlotCube;

    // The event sender is modified: 
    plotcube.Rotation = Matrix4.Identity;
    float max = 1000f;
    plotcube.Limits.YMax = max;
    plotcube.Limits.XMax = max;
    plotcube.Limits.ZMax = max;
    plotcube.Limits.YMin = -max;
    plotcube.Limits.XMin = -max;
    plotcube.Limits.ZMin = -max;
    plotcube.AspectRatioMode = AspectRatioMode.MaintainRatios;

    // disable the default double click handler which would reset the scene
    a.Cancel = true;
    // trigger a redraw of the scene
    a.Refresh = true;
};
```

Inside the handler, we could fetch a reference to some scene object by `ilPanel.Scene.First<ILPlotCube>()...`. But instead, we take the object provided by `s` which is the target of the fired event. This corresponds to the synchronized version of the plot cube - the one which is used for rendering. Use this instead and your changes will show up properly.